# Button that calls a function causing parameter for called function to become empty?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm having some difficulty pinpoint what I believe is a logic error of some sort in a function I've created to search an input file.

The function takes a string, then searches the file like normal on the first run. Afterwards, the value becomes blank (without any code to do so) and the search finds no matches. Here is the function in question:

```
public String searchByName(String str) {
    String value = str.trim().replace(" ", "");
    String st = "\nResults:\n";

    for (SeaPort port:ports) {
        if (port.name.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            st += "\nPort: " + port.name + " " + port.index;
        }
        ArrayList<Dock> docks = port.getDocks();
        for (Dock dock:docks) {
            if (dock.name.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                st += dock.toString();
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Person> persons = port.getPersons();
        for (Person person:persons) {
            if (person.name.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                st += person.toString();
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Ship> ships = port.getShips();
        for (Ship ship:ships) {
            if (ship.name.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                st += ship.toString();
            }
        }
    }

    return st;

}
```

Additionally, here is the function behind the action listener on the button that calls the above:

```
public void searchFile() {
    if (file == null) {
        textArea.append("\nCannot search. Please select a file first.");
    } else {
        world = new World(sc);

        String term = textField.getText();
        String selection = (String) searchOptions.getSelectedItem();

        switch (selection) {
        case "Index":
            int i;
            try {
                i = Integer.parseInt(term);
                textArea.append("\nSearching for " + i + " by " + selection + "\n\n");
                textArea.append(world.searchByIndex(i));

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                textArea.append("\nError with input. Number required to search ID");
            }
            break;
        case "Type":
            textArea.append("\nSearching for " + term + " by " + selection + "\n\n");
            textArea.append(world.searchByType(term));
            break;
        case "Name":
            textArea.append("\nSearching for " + term + " by " + selection + "\n\n");
            textArea.append(world.searchByName(term));
            System.out.println(term);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What I find bizarre is that my test print statement continues to hold the string, but does not print the result. Here is a screenshot after pressing "Search" twice in a row:
[image]

I cannot think of what could be causing this issue. Originally in developing all three methods I thought that the switch statement was causing the error, so I waited to build this method before further troubleshooting. However, there is so break in this code. Could the issue be that there is only one SeaPort in port?

Comment: [mcve] would help quite a bit here

Comment: If I were a betting man though I'd say that your problem is with your `world` variable, perhaps because you appear to be trying to open a file, one that may already have been open with the first search. Was it ever closed? What values does world hold on first and second searches? Time for you to do more debugging I think.

Comment: Apologies, I really wasn't sure how to explain the problem. You nailed it, though. The error was in the world variable. It's odd, I tested it before completing the function with the other functions that perform similar operations. Whatever the case, thank you for your help!